# IE 10 special characters

Tags: internet-explorer, special-characters

I'm using a Windows 8 64 bit laptop with IE 10 installed.

I have a problem regarding special characters in IE 10. My OS is English however I'm using a Turkish keyboard.

Now in Chrome, Firefox I absolutely have no problem but in IE 10 any kind of text input I get other characters when I try to type some special characters in Turkish:

For example:

"Fıstıkçı Şahap" is what can I write in Chrome but in IE the same entry shows as:

"f1st1kç1 _ahap"

So I get "1" instead of "ı" and "_" instead of "ş".

Why do you think this is happening and what is the solution?

Comment: Just to confirm.  You have installed the appropriate keyboard and are also using a physical Turkish keyboard correct?  Have you tried updating to Windows 8.1 and thus tried IE11?

Comment: Hello, yes of course. As stated I have no other issues elsewhere in Windows, Chrome, Office whatever comes in mind. I cannot update to Windows 8.1 or IE11 since this is a corporate laptop.